# Change color from transparent to normal color using fade for button

Tags: android, button, fadein

what i basically want is for a circle button to fade away when they switch is pressed on and fade back to how it was when the switch is On. I figured out a way for fade out animation, but i cannot seem to get it back aagain after it is transaprent.

My code

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            aSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (aSwitch.isChecked()) {
                        Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.0f);
                        anim.setDuration(800);
                        changer.startAnimation(anim);

                        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                database.child("Lock Status").addValueEventListener(listener);
                                checklive = true;
                                PerformCommands();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                changer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                            }
                        });
                        System.out.println("Switch On");
                    }
                    else{
                        count = 0;
                        checklive = false;
                        System.out.println("Switch Off");
                        changer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                        changer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked){
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please go live first to unlock and lock door", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please go live first to unlock and lock door", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        text.setText("Waiting to go live....");
                        database.child("Lock Status").removeEventListener(listener);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

My button XML

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="315dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
    android:text=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.944"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.702" />
```

Circle button XML

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

<size android:height="283dp" android:width="283dp"/>
<solid android:color="#666c68"/>

<corners android:radius="278dp"/>
```

If anyone could help me with transition I would be very grateful. Thank you

Comment: You have an `if (aSwitch.isChecked())` block, where you run the fade-out animation, why won't you run the reverse animation in the `else` block? `AlphaAnimation(0.0f,1.0f)`

Comment: Would that work? Since the button is now transparent?

Comment: It may, you just inverse the transaction from `1.0f, 0.0f` to `0.0f, 1.0f`, try to do it.